# Different languages on Glass voice recognizer

Tags: google-glass

I would like to have a command with a word from Brazilian Portuguese.

Does someone know if there's any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: umm, that is really high-end technology :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For voice recognition input and processing in Glass. You should follow steps given at... https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware

Comment: Thanks Shankar, but I've already read that. What I'd like to do is to add a specific name that is from Brazilian Portuguese. Do you know if there's any way, maybe getting in contact with Google so they can add the word to the service?

Best regards,

Comment: Have you used intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "pt");  in code?